# Regular expression: limit number of characters

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a textbox and need to limit number of characters in it (no more than 1000).
This is the regular expression i have: `^.{0,1000}$`
it works great until there is a newline in a textbox (when I hit enter). If there is newline in textbox it shows me the warning "you have more than 2000 characters". Is there workaround of this issue.

Comment: sounds like you're using a multi-line text box or textarea, is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` doesn't match all characters (i.e. newlines), so you can use two characters groups to get *all* characters, like this:

```
^[\s\S]{0,1000}$
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code does not work. When I add anycharacter it says it is over limit. <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="description" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Over 2000" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0, 2000}$" />

Comment: Sorry, the space after the comma was the issue.  Should work once you take that out

Answer (score 1):

Set the `RegexOptions.SingleLine` flag.

Alternatively, you could explicitly include newlines in the regex: `^(\n|.){0,1000}$`

Comment: I'd guess OP is using a `RegularExpressionValidator`, so setting flags probably isn't an option in this case (though that's a great suggestion otherwise).

Comment: @bdukes: That's why I added the alternative.

Comment: Yeah, Im using RegularExpressionValidator. unfortunately this code does not work neither: ^(\n|.){,1000}$. Keep saying that Im over limit with any characters now.

Comment: You need the `0` before the comma, it's not actually a valid regex to do `{,1000}` (though it seems like it should be).